# MT5 API всегда неверный логин пароль

Tags: mt5

Несколько месяцев назад я зарегистрировал демо счет в МТ5 для написания своего торгового ПО. Все работало замечательно, я получал токен и работал с остальным функционалом апишки. Но недавно при попытке пройти авторизацию возвращает сообщение "Server returned INVALID_ACCOUNT just 80 seconds ago. Please wait 10000 seconds to try again."

Пробовал создать новый аккаунт через МТ5 как раньше делал и пробовал с помощью запроса в АПИ на создание демо счета - все равно то же самое сообщение. Что изменилось? Как теперь работать с апишкой?

адрес апи https://mt5.mtapi.be/index.html